# Information not being recorded in Parse

Tags: javascript, json, html, parse-platform

I am working with Parse for Javascript, and below is my dilema:

During the signup process, along with the username, and password, the first and last name of the user would have to recorded into parse. As of now, only the username and password is stored.

Below is the javascript signup function code:

```
SignUp: function(e) {
      var self = this;
      var username = this.$("#signup-username").val();
      var password = this.$("#signup-password").val();
            var first_name = this.$("#fname").val();
                        var last_name = this.$("#lname").val();



      Parse.User.signUp(username, password, { ACL: new Parse.ACL() }, {
        success: function(user) {
            user.set("first_name", first_name);
            user.set("last_name", last_name);
          new ManageTodosView();
          self.undelegateEvents();
          delete self;
        },
```

Below is the html form code (ask user to enter their information):

```
   <form class="signup-form">
          <h2>Sign Up</h2>
          <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
               <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Please enter your First Name" />
                    <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Please enter your Last Name" />
          <input type="email" id="signup-username" placeholder="Please enter your email" />
          <input type="password" id="signup-password" placeholder="Create a Password" />
          <button>Sign Up</button>
        </form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User.set won't save the changes you will need to call save once you set the first name and last name. Also you don't need to do this after calling signing up. Try the code below it should work.

```
SignUp: function(e) {
      var self = this;
      var username = this.$("#signup-username").val();
      var password = this.$("#signup-password").val();
      var first_name = this.$("#fname").val();
      var last_name = this.$("#lname").val();
      var user = new Parse.User();
      user.set("username", username);
      user.set("password", password);
      user.set("first_name", first_name);
      user.set("last_name", last_name);


      user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
          new ManageTodosView();
          self.undelegateEvents();
          delete self;
      }


 }
```